# MySQL get_lock('test_lock', 0) always returns 1

Tags: mysql, semaphore

As I understand it, get_lock('test_lock', 0) should return 1, or success, after the first call. A second call should return 0. After a release_lock('test_lock') is called, it would return 1 again. Is that right? I'm just using MySQL Workbench to run the commands and getting back a 1 each time. I was hoping to use this lock as a semaphore in my application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you successfully call `get_lock`, your session owns it, so subsequent calls from the same session will also succeed (and return 1). If you run `get_lock` and then open **another** MySQL Workbench session (e.g., by launching another instance of the application) and try to obtain the same lock, it will fail (and return 0).